# KSH Pattern from variable does not work

Tags: scripting, regular-expression, ksh, posix, patterns

Could somebody explain me why pattern in Korn shell (assigned to variable) works this way:

```
u@h:w$ pattern='file_[0-9][0-9]'
u@h:w$ ls $pattern
file_01  file_02  file_03
```

But it doesn't work for smarter pattern `file_{2}([0-9])`:

```
$ pattern='file_{2}([0-9])'
$ ls $pattern
ls: file_{2}([0-9]): No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4):

That's intentional, to avoid breaking POSIX compliance (though initially it was to avoid breaking Bourne compatibility).

```
echo file_{2}([0-9])
```

would be invalid code in Bourne/POSIX `sh`, so `ksh` is free to interpret it as it wants. But:

```
pattern='file_{2}([0-9])'
echo $pattern
```

is valid Bourne/POSIX `sh` code, and as per POSIX, is meant to match on files named like `file_{2}(0)`, `file_{2}(1)`...

The extended operators are not available when they are the result of an expansion, even if you use:

```
echo @($pattern)
```

You'd need to use `eval`, or you could also use `FIGNORE`:

```
FIGNORE="!($pattern)"; echo *
```

(beware it affects the expansion of hidden files though, make it `FIGNORE="@(.*|!($pattern))"` if you don't expect the glob to expand hidden files).

Note that `bash` and `zsh` later adopted some of those `ksh` extended operators (though not the `{x,y}(...)` one) but they addressed the POSIX compliance/Bourne compatibility differently: they make those extended globs available in all contexts but only when a specific option is enabled (`kshglob` in `zsh`, `extglob` in `bash`). That means however that it makes it difficult for them to add more operators without breaking their own backward compatibility. For instance, if `bash` added the `{x,y}(...)` operator now, it could break scripts that expect `a='{1}(2){3}'; [[ $a = $a ]]` to return true.